# Simple jabber server

Tags: linux, xmpp

advise simple Jabber server.

I need only the function of conferences.

Internal users do not need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may want to try ejabberd: http://www.ejabberd.im/

Answer (score 0):

Wikipedia has a very [extensive comparison of available XMPP servers](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Comparison_of_XMPP_server_software). Maybe take a look and see what best serves your purpose.